# 301 Redirect Best Practices - multiple sites to single site

Tags: iis, redirect

I have around 15+ sites, and we want to drop these sites and merge them into only one site (create pages for each one in the new site).

The 15+ site's domains should be redirected to one site as below:

```
a.com -> z.com/a
b.com -> z.com/b
c.com -> z.com/c
..
```

Also, we want to redirect (301) page by page from the old domains to the new the new domain to keep the page's ranking:

```
 a.com/about-us     -> z.com/a/about-us
 b.com/about/abouus -> z.com/b/about-s
 c.com/contactus    -> z.com/c/contact-us
```

Each one of the 15+ sites is running on its own server with a different platform while the new server is IIS.

Currently, I'm thinking of two approaches:

1. Point the old DNS records to the new server of z.com, and handle all the redirects on the server.
2. Keep the old site running, and configure redirect rules on each server to redirect each page to the matching page on the new site.

Which approach is better, any other approaches? So far I think the first approach is better since we will control all the redirects in one place - but from the performance wise, is it going to add more headache on the server?

Answer (score 7):

### The Scenario

You created a new site and you want to redirect all old sites(15+) to new site (page to page).

All old sites are running in it's own server on different platforms whereas the new one is IIS.

### Your options

1. *Point the old DNS records to the new server of z.com, and handle all the redirects on the server.*

Advantage

---

- Less cost - you can remove all old sites and the server cost can be saved.
- Internal redirection. So, time will be less

Disadvantage

---

- Complex to perform
- take care of conflict of similar pages(double check the redirection path)

---

2. *Keep the old site running, and configure redirect rules on each server to redirect each page to the matching page on the new site*

If you can afford the cost of running 15 different sites on 15 servers just to redirect, then only go for this method.

It is just a waste of money and the redirection time will be more.

Answer (score 6):

I think eventually you'll have to shutdown all the other sites as in the long term unlikely does it make sense to keep 15 sites running just to do the redirects.

So as I understand the question is rather on how to better organize the migration to the new system in the short term. So here are my thoughts on this:

#### how huge is your system

- what's your QPS?
- how many pages do you have across your sites farm?
- do you need to remap URLS for a decent amount of pages?
- what's the migration procedure? Will you switch your sites one-by-one or it's technically infeasible and they all need to be swtiched over at once?

If we're talking about a system handling 10 QPS and 1K pages or about a system handling 
50K QPS and having 1B pages we need to dynamically remap system load may be a concern and *p.2* may look better

#### rollbacks

note that DNS records can be cached by intermediate servers and if you need to quickly rollback to the previous version if something goes wrong it can be an issue

#### what kind of systems do you have

Is it actually possible to easily extract URLs from 15 diverse systems and put them to a single point without a risk to lose something valuable?

#### ease of maintenance

At first glance the first approach looks easier from the maintenance perspective, but I don't know what kind of system you use and how complex the redirection rules need to be.
If they are complex dynamic ones like *a.com/product.php?id=1* => *z.com/a/iPhone6S* moving millions of such urls to a single point could be tricky

#### SEO

I don't follow the industry closely, but a few years ago both would work ok. I think it's worth consulting those keeping up to date with this industry - it changes very rapidly

Answer (score 5):

Your first approach is definitely the best.

1. It is easy to maintain
2. You needn't to keep old infrastructure (though in your second case you'll need to keep only redirecting frontend like apache, nginx or lighthttpd)
3. There are no performance risks as from one visitor request to old location, redirect answer and than request to new location will come in turn and not simultaneously.

Comment: A 10 lines nodejs script running is enough to redirect xD No need for a full webserver

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 

The question is If I use DNS redirects I will be able to redirect a.com/ --> z.com/a/ ?

This going to be a DNS forward not changing the IP of the DNS record right? Also, the redirection will have complex logic on the z.com server.

Comment: @AhmadHarb DNS can affect only server name resolving, it can't redirect to subfolder like `z.com/a`. So you need to have a web service, which answer on `a.com` requests with 301 redirect to `z.com/a`.
So it is a HTTP redirect.

Answer (score 2):

DNS records are not capable of HTTP redirection which is crucial for [SEO](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection). To make sure your redirect is 301 HTTP redirect you can use [sniffer](http://testuri.org/sniffer).

The answer is just make sure your redirect is 301 HTTP redirect so you get your SEO right. Other than that it's just a matter of taste / architecture / money rather than standards.

**UPDATE**

Read more:

- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

  > Both Bing and Google recommend using a 301 redirect to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results.
- [ehow.com](http://www.ehow.com/info_12225977_point-dns-vs-301-redirect.html)

  > A 301 redirect is a search-engine friendly way to move a domain. The 301-redirected domain does not cause duplicate content in the search engines so that you do not harm your search engine rank. Using a new DNS setting is required to have a new domain name, but it does not redirect browsers or search engines. Both of these methods are used to move to a new domain.
- [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53398)

  > Duplicate content occurs when the same content is available on two different URLs. To prevent duplicate content on www vs no-www, use 301 redirects to redirect one to the other. To implement redirects, it is the webserver that needs to be configured properly. As long as DNS is pointing to the webserver (either CNAME or A record), then the webserver can be configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this problem some months back.  I wanted to redirect a whole site into a new site's structure.  The old site was .php which I know nothing about.

I figured I'd point the old website's DNS at my server and write some MVC code to catch every request, and then use a set of rules using the vb.net `Like` operator to compare the inbound Url with my ruleset.

It worked a treat.  I redirect 300+ pages to my new site with about 10 rules.  These include changes of folder structure, a forum (which was mainly junk but had a few good questions), and I implement a "catchall" rule which points to the new home page, in case I missed something.

It worked so well I've packaged it up as a commercial product and it publically available.  It is free with link from the destination site (in your case just the single destination site).

https://301redirect.website/

There are a couple of demo videos on the homepage which will explain the setup in a few minutes.